# removing characters from string if it's not in the regex

Tags: php, regex

basically i want to remove unwanted characters from string - i have a list of valid characters in a regex or map ( or whatever that is )

```
$permitted_uri_chars = ' ) ( ( ) a-z 0-9~%.+:_\-  δ ο κ ι μ ή χ ό ν';
```

right now i'm using this code which seems slow and messy and above all i have to write every single character ( i cant do a-z 0-9 )

```
 $string = "this is a test";
 $permitted_uri_chars = ' ) ( ( ) a b c d e z 0 1 2 3 4 9 _ - δ ο κ ι μ ή χ ό ν'; 
 $permitted_uri_chars = explode(' ' , $permitted_uri_chars );
 $unwanted = array();

 for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($string) ; $i++)
 {
     if(!in_array($string[$i] , $permitted_uri_chars ))
     $unwanted[] = $string[$i] ;
 }
 $string = str_replace($unwanted, '-' , $string);
 echo $string;
```

Comment: Is your input utf8-encoded? And your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) is probably the best tool for the job:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\da-z~%\.\+:_\-δοκιμήχόν]/i', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) here instead, using a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

**Note**: Not clear if parentheses are permitted, but you can remove them if you need to. I included them since you have multiple in `$permitted_uri_chars`.

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9δοκιμήχόν_()%~.:+-]/i', '', $string);
```